# Any alternative to Jquerymobile in rhodes for Windows Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, rhomobile, rhodes, windows-mobile-6

I'm building one project for Cross Platforms like ios, Android, Windows Mobile using Rhostudio.

I'm using jQueryMobile to get a nice look and feel. 
All the stuffs going well untill, Windows Mobile comes to play.

As there is no support for jquerymobile in windows mobile, i'm not getting the proper Ui output for it.

Is their any other way we can get the same looks and feels for the windows mobile as like Android or ios ?

Thanks,
Ashis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/, there is A-grade support for jQM on Windows Mobile.

If you want a native look and feel, you can try a theme developed specifically to emulate the Windows look and feel, such as http://sgrebnov.github.com/jqmobile-metro-theme/samples/jqm-public-demo/index.html.

Comment: Are you Ryan Bates of railscasts.com? :-/